# Prevent skipping of an element in Flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am working on a slider, where I don't want the user to be able to skip image in my slider. So I want them to only be able to either click 1 forward or 1 backward using the bullet navigations.

Here is what I have tried so far, without success:

1. A piece of JavaScript to get to the bullets:

```
// an outside javascript function
var preventBulletSkipping: function() {
    $(".flex-control-paging").each(function(i, sliderPaging) {
        $("li", sliderPaging).on("mousedown", function(e) {
            var $li = $(this);
            var $bullets = $li.siblings().andSelf();
            var bulletIndex = $bullets.index($li);
            var $next = $("a.flex-active", (($bullets.length-1) == bulletIndex ? $bullets.first() : $li.next()));
            var $prev = $("a.flex-active", (0 == bulletIndex ? $bullets.last() : $li.prev()));

            if (!$next.length && !$prev.length) {
                // I get here when I expect to, but I can't prevent the click from happening
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Which gets me to where I want to be, but I can't prevent the click from firing and the slide changes.

My next approach would have been to use the `before`-callback of Flexslider, like so:

```
$('.bulletgallery .flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    before: function(slider) {
        var currentSlide = slider.currentSlide;
        var nextSlide = slider.getTarget("next");
        var prevSlide = slider.getTarget("prev");

        // dead end, as currentSlide already points to the bullet clicked
    }
});
```

But that didn't work, because in that callback, the `currentSlide` was already pointing to the bullet I clicked.

So, any idea here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after much time being away from this, I have found a solution and I am pretty happy about it. For readability I have made a lot of variables. :-)

```
$(".bulletgallery .flex-control-paging li a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $bullets = $(this).parent().siblings().andSelf();
    var $me = $(this).parent();
    var $active = $(".flex-active", $bullets).parent();
    var meIndex = $bullets.index($me);
    var activeIndex = $bullets.index($active);

    if (meIndex == activeIndex) {
        return;
    }

    var $slider = $(this).parents('.flexslider');

    // if clicked on an item beyond or past the currently active slide, only move one
    if (meIndex > activeIndex) {
        $slider.flexslider('next');
    } else {
        $slider.flexslider('prev');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps anyone!